# Speeding up a LIKE query in MySQL with 100 million rows

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to clean up a database that has about 100 million rows. It's pretty straightforward - valid entries must contain a particular character, so a `DELETE FROM list WHERE content NOT LIKE '%#%'` would do it.

The problem is that LIKE queries are *brutally* slow with this many records.  I'm sure adding an index would help, but in normal use it will never be queried in this manner, and disk space is at a premium (which is why I'm doing the cleanup).

Is there a way to speed this up?

Comment: `LIKE` queries are punishingly slow. Use a full-text index or some other way if identifying which columns contain that character. You cannot index for `LIKE` when doing arbitrary substring matches, it requires a painful, expensive table-scan.

Comment: I figured.  Is there any reasonably performant way to eliminate rows that don't contain a specific character other than using LIKE?

Comment: A substring with wildcards at both ends will be painfully slow over 100 million. If that substring is literally the hash character as you have in the question then even a full text index might not assist. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-stopwords.html

Comment: If the task is concerned more on cleaning up the database periodically, my suggestion would be to go for the following: Add a column for flagging the status of the record with tinyint datatype default to 0. Use a trigger (Add/Update) which will setup the flag value to be valid(1) or leave it to (zero). Finally in your clean up routine, delete all records which equals the value 0 in this column(This column also has to be indexed)

Comment: Why not dump this to CSV, rip through it with a scripting language, clean it up in any other ways necessary, and then load it back in clean? If your machine is space or CPU constrained you can always work with this on a machine much better equipped to solve the problem.

Comment: have you tried using `REGEXP` instead of `LIKE` in the script?

Comment: It is more about cleaning up periodically, or in clusters.  Is there a way to speed up doing it bit by bit?  I tried putting a LIMIT of 1,000 on the query but it was still comically slow.

Comment: For your first run, speed should not really matter, but you may want to do it in chunks (e.g. `where id >= 10000 and id <= 20000`) to e.g. reduce locking. For periodically tasks, it depends on your situation. If you e.g. only append rows, you can skip ids you already cleaned last week. Or mark updated/new row as Heartine proposed with a trigger/generated column + index on it. Or don't store invalid rows at all. Or delete them instead of update them when they become invalid. Very generally: databases use space to make queries faster. If you want speed without using space, you are at an impasse.